# Is it possible to add input textbox in 'send an email(V2)' of Power automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list, power-automate, send-email

I want to trigger an email to outlook via Power Automate. This email will have an input text box and 3 hyperlinks and the recipient would be able to add his comment in the textbox and click any of the hyperlinks which will save his comment mentioned in the textbox to the SharePoint list. can this be achieved.

Comment: Would you please provide more information about when to send email? An item has been created in SharePoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this would easily be possible from Send an Email(V2). There is another task of Sending an Email with Options, however it does not allow you to easily capture information, evidenced in [some other forums.](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Send-email-with-options-and-record-responses/td-p/501174)

Instead of the Email Tasks you could use the Start and Wait for an Approval Task.

This allows you to have Custom Responses (Buttons) along with an optional Comment field which you should be able to make use of after the "Approval" has been actioned to save the information into a list.

Use a Switch Condition to capture the Outcome of the Approval and save the comment into the appropriate location as required. You will need to use an Apply To Each to get the comment from the Approval but if you use the "Wait for one Response" there should only be one loop.

**Approval:**

[image]

**Switch:**

[image]

**Example Email:**

[image]